# eventos de toque (touch event) javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, touch

Muy buenas.
Estoy haciendo un juego en canvas para moviles y tengo un problema con los eventos touch.

Utilizo el clientX, para mover el jugador, si es en el centro de la pantalla saltará, y si es a los lados pues se moverá a este mismo.

Utilizando e.touches[0] y e.touches[1] consigo que el personaje pueda moverse y saltar a la vez cuando se recibe un segundo toque.

El problema viene cuando uno de los e.touches no acaba en el mismo clientX definido para esa acción, y si empiezo el toque en el centro y lo termino a la derecha el personaje sigue saltando...

Os dejo el codigo de los eventos a ver si podeis ayudarme

```
var jumping = false;
    window.addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){
        if(e.touches[0].clientX > (canvas.width / 4) * 3 ){
            player.key.right = true;
        } else if(e.touches[0].clientX < (canvas.width / 4)) {
            player.key.left = true;
        } else {
            player.key.up = true;
            jumping = true;
            setTimeout(function() {

                jumping = false
            }, 25);
        }
        if(e.touches[1]) {
            if(jumping){
                if(e.touches[1].clientX > (canvas.width / 4) * 3 ){
                    player.key.right = true;
                } else if(e.touches[1].clientX < (canvas.width / 4)) {
                    player.key.left = true;
                }
            } else {
                player.key.up = true;
            }
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener("touchend",function(e){
        if(e.changedTouches[0].clientX > (canvas.width / 4)*3){
            player.key.right = false
        } else if(e.changedTouches[0].clientX < (canvas.width / 4)) {
            player.key.left = false;
        } else {
            player.key.up = false;
            jumping = false;
        }
        if(e.changedTouches[1]){
            player.key.up = false;
            jumping = false;
        }
    })
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

RESUELTO!:

He creado una variable para saber el numero de toques activos que hay en la pantalla, así si hay un único toque y se finaliza todas las key del jugador quedan en false, y si no, pues solo queda activa la que sigue pulsada.

Os dejo el código por si alguien lo necesita.

```
var touches = 0;
window.addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){
        touches++;
        if(e.touches[0].clientX > (canvas.width / 4) * 3 ){
            player.key.right = true;
        } else if(e.touches[0].clientX < (canvas.width / 4)) {
            player.key.left = true;
        } else {
            player.key.up = true;
            jumping=true;
        }
        if(e.touches[1]) {
            if(jumping){
                if(e.touches[1].clientX > (canvas.width / 4) * 3 ){
                    player.key.right = true;
                } else if(e.touches[1].clientX < (canvas.width / 4)) {
                    player.key.left = true;
                }
            } else {
                player.key.up = true;
            }
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener("touchend",function(e){
        touches--;
        if(touches > 0){
            if(e.changedTouches[0].clientX > (canvas.width / 4)*3){
                player.key.right = false;
            } else if(e.changedTouches[0].clientX < (canvas.width / 4)) {
                player.key.left = false;
            } else {
                player.key.up = false;
            }
        } else {
            player.key.up = false;
            player.key.left = false;
            player.key.right = false;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solución. Recuerda marcar tu propia respuesta como correcta luego de 2 días.